# Android zxing orientation: ResultMetaData is null, Get Rotation/Orientation

Tags: android, null, qr-code, zxing

I am working on an app that reads QR codes and I need the orientation of the code.
The ZXING source states that the orientation can be obtained from a hashtable **ResultMetaData** through the key *ORIENTATION*

Now, my issue is that the **getResultMetaData()** is not returning any results when I run the following:

```
orientation = (Integer) Returned[v].getResultMetadata().get("ORIENTATION");
```

However, the line directly above this,

```
points = Returned[v].getResultPoints();
```

Works just fine, so I know that the code is being read, and it is returning data.

Does anyone know of a fix for this or a different method of obtaining the orientation?

One last note: I am using **QRCodeMultiReader** which is why *Returned* is an array.

Thanks, 
Zander

***EDIT*** I just found that **getResultMetaData** only supports orientation for 1D barcodes, So I guess the questions is now: How do I get the orientation of a QR code?

***EDIT #2*** Here is the code to get the rotation (doesn't support perspective)

```
ResultPoint a= points[1];
ResultPoint b= points[2];
ResultPoint c= points[0];
float distance = Math.abs(a.getX()-b.getX());
RectF rect = new RectF(a.getX(), a.getY(), a.getX()+distance, a.getY()+distance);
//Find the degree of the rotation that is needed
double z = Math.abs(a.getX()-b.getX());
double x = Math.abs(a.getY()-b.getY());
double theta = Math.atan(x/z);

if((b.getX()<a.getX())&&(b.getY()>a.getY())){//-+   
    theta=180-theta;
}else if((b.getX()<a.getX())&&(b.getY()<a.getY())){//--
    theta=180+theta;
}else if((b.getX()>a.getX())&&(b.getY()<a.getY())){ //+-
    theta=360-theta;
}
//theta stores the degree of rotation
```

Comment: To simply explain the behavior: orientation doesn't really describe the barcode, but, the orientation of the image in which a barcode was found. For QR codes this is rather unnecessary since it can be found, by its nature, in any orientation of the image.

Comment: @SeanOwen
 I am drawing an overlay over the code, orientation is needed.

Comment: OK. That doesn't change the answer as to what orientation means here.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689210/qr-codes-camera-orientation-projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result has a getResultPoints method. That will return the locations of the finder patterns (the large black squares) in a QR code. Since those appear top-left, top-right, and bottom-left of the code, you can figure out the orientation that they describe. There are some static helper methods in the ResultPoint class.

For an image with no perspective, the three points should describe an isosceles right triangle. If there is perspective, things get more complicated.

Comment: Correct, though they actually appear in the order bottom-left, top-left, top-right. The bottom-right alignment pattern appears as the fourth element if it exists, which it does in all but version 1 QR codes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct calculation takes in consideration only the segment between a and b points and the angle defined between the coordinates axis. It adjusts the degree depending on the quadrant. Neither 'distance' nor 'rect' vars are required to make this calculation:

```
ResultPoint a= points[1];
ResultPoint b= points[2];
ResultPoint c= points[0];

double z = Math.abs(a.getX()-b.getX());
double x = Math.abs(a.getY()-b.getY());
double theta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(x/z));

        // Quadrants 0 and 1
        if(a.getY() > b.getY()) {
            if(a.getX() > b.getX()) {
                theta = 90 + (90 - theta);
            }
        }
        // Quadrants 2 or 3
        else {
            if (a.getX() > b.getX()) {
                theta = 180 + theta;
            }
            else {
                theta = 360 - theta;
            }
        }

        return theta;
```